# Classification based on categorical features

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

**Dataset:**

| Team | Opponent | Home/Away | Ground | Match Date | Match Year | Match Period | Margin | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | Country B | Away | Ground1 | 20-09-2016 | 2016 | Sep-16 | 5 wickets | Lost |
| Country C | Country D | Away | Ground2 | 08-07-2012 | 2012 | Jul-12 | 66 runs | Won |

The target column for prediction is **Result**, which is a binary classification with values either **Won or Lost**

Aim is to predict whether the match result of a given team (team1), against an opponent (team2) at a given ground, is Won or Lost, so the input to the ML model from the user would be **Team, Opponent, Ground**.

The accuracy of the model is pretty low when only categorical columns are considered as input.

Any help on methods to train the ML model with just categorical variables..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the categorical variables to binary, so the ML models can understand it. I would split match column into two columns each one has one country, then convert every country to a unique binary or a value. The model can then understand your approach

Comment: Yes @Mohamed Afify, that is how it is done already, but the ML model doesn't perform/ learn well when only categorical variables are provided as input